# Getting a specific part from XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get the PAY where it has the ID 3 Where it says the label phone
but i really dont know how, i tried everything.
Thanks for helping!

Here is the XML code:

```
$books = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
  <login>1</login>
  <arrStatsData>
    <item>
      <Id>500</Id>
      <Label>website_name</Label>
      <Data>
        <item>
          <Id>4</Id>
          <Label>transactions</Label>
          <Data>
            <sum>2029.34</sum>
            <cst>47.67575</cst>
            <num>86</num>
            <avg>23.6</avg>
            <pay>1981.66</pay>
          </Data>
        </item>
        <item>
          <Id>3</Id>
          <Label>Phone</Label>
          <Data>
            <sum>205</sum>
            <cst>17.353</cst>
            <num>205</num>
            <avg>1</avg>
            <pay>187.647</pay>
          </Data>
        </item>

......
```

PHP Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($arrResult); //load xml from above
foreach($xml->arrStatsData->item->Data as $item) 
{
    foreach($item->item as $DATA)
{
       echo $DATA->Id.'<br>';

}
```

My result now is:

```
1981.66
187.647
-0.4448
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you know some information that's tell the node apart from the rest you can use XPath to get the value directly instead of iterating through all of them:

```
<?php
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($books);
$pay = $sxe->xpath('//item[./Id=3]/Data/pay');

echo (string) $pay[0];
```

#### Ouput:

```
187.647
```

Comment: You do not need to cast to string with echo - it does not hurt much either, just saying in case you didn't know.

Comment: If you need to get extracted XML part back as XML string, you can use [`asXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code would be like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($books);

foreach($xml->arrStatsData->item->Data as $item) 
{
    //echo '$item;';
    foreach($item->item as $DATA)
    {
       if($DATA->Id == '3'){
           echo $DATA->Data->pay."<br/>";
       }
    }
}
```

It retrieve the pay value when the ID is equals to 3.

Comment: Thank you all! The thing i wanted to accomplish was far more extensive, but i just needed the basics, thanks to that i finished my script. topic closed

Comment: @user2370950: This is not a forum (so we do not have topics), however if you want to mark your question as answered, select the checkmark on the answer: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - Also you might be interested in the [basic simplexml usage examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic).

Comment: @user2370950. You're welcome. If this worked for you, check this answer as the solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Rolando Isidoro was faster to recommend `xpath`, my solution is slightly different, that's why I post it, too:

```
$pay = (string)$xml->xpath("//item[Id = '3']/Data/pay")[0];
echo $pay;
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qzPlmp